# Abolish does not work as expected

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I just tried the following abbreviation with Tim Pope's Abolish-Plugin:

```
:Abolish and AND
```

What I expect is:

```
and changes to AND
And changes to AND
```

The first one works, the latter one does not; 'And' stays 'And'.

Any ideas?

I use the latest Version of the Plugin.

Comment: Problem with a plugin? Start by reading the documentation, then use its issue tracker then use google then come here. The solution is usually found between step 1 and step 2.

Comment: Believe me, I have done all these steps before! I simply misunderstood its possibilities...

Answer (score 1):

I think you are misinterpreting what Abolish does for you.

```
:Abolish and AND
```

is equivalent to having the following abbreviations (you can check this by looking at the output of `:iabbrev`)

```
iabbrev  AND AND
iabbrev  and AND
iabbrev  And And
```

Abolish gives you mapping that turn all lowercase into the right hand side. All uppercase into the Uppercase version of the right hand side. And a mapping for the when the left hand side has the only the first letter capitalized. (like you are typing a sentence).

I am not sure if there is a way to get what you want from Abolish.

Comment: Oh, ok. Thanks for this elucidation. What a pity :(